# How to change the DNS server across network interfaces?

Tags: networking, 14.04, dns, settings

The only consistent solution for changing your DNS server is to change it in each individual network interface. This means for Ethernet and for each wireless network you use.

I'm looking for a way to set DNS servers globally. No matter what interface I'm using. I found several solutions but most of them are commented on that they only work on certain conditions.

Because I don't really know a way to test if the DNS settings were succesfully changed, I'm looking for a way that definitely works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `resolvconf` if it isn't already installed use: `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`.

Then edit the config file: `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`.
Enter your nameserves (one per line) with: `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
Update resolvconf with `sudo resolvconf -u`

Changes should be permanent and for all interfaces.

Comment: You need to update resolvconf  for the settings to be applied. sudo resolvconf -u

Comment: What do I change to the file for adding new DNS nameservers?

Comment: (The file is empty when I try to edit it, is that correct?)

Comment: It is okay that it is empty just write: `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: Pabi, might be worth updating your answer with further details added in these comments :)

Comment: use `sudo editor file` so everyone can load their favourite editor.